# How to access fields from a goal when creating a node with Rules?

Tags: rules, 7

I'm trying to create a rule with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module that posts a node when users achieve a goal (using the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module 7.x-1.3). I want to get fields from the goal like the goal image and other fields, but there's no data selector for the goal completed.

I can't find a way to fetch the completed goal entity. I've tried using a data comparison condition, but it'll only give "goal" data selector without any fields.

Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried the 'entity has field', or 'entity is of bundle' conditions on the goal? Sometimes that is required to have the desired fields show up.

Comment: Yeah, but it only gives me site and awarded-user selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) export format), which is an example of how to get this to work:

```
{ "rules_show_a_message_after_goal_completion" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show a message after goal completion",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "goals" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "goals", "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "goal_awarded" : [] },
    "IF" : [ { "goals_goal_condition" : { "goal_id" : "2" } } ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_fetch" : {
          "USING" : { "type" : "goal", "id" : "2" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "goal_fetched" : "Fetched goal" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Some details about the \u0022[goal-fetched:ftitle\u0022 goal which you just completed:\u003Cbr \/\u003E\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n- \u003Cstrong\u003EGoal Description\u003C\/strong\u003E = [goal-fetched:field-goal-description]\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n- \u003Cstrong\u003EGoal Category\u003C\/strong\u003E = [goal-fetched:field-goal-category]\u003Cbr \/\u003E\r\n- \u003Cstrong\u003EGoal Level\u003C\/strong\u003E = [goal-fetched:field-goal-level]\u003Cbr \/\u003E" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some details about this rule:

- Rules Event: "***`A goal is completed by a user`***", as in your question.
- Rules Condition: "***`The goal completed by a user`***", a Rules Condition provided by the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer). In my case, I used the goal with goal id = "`2`" (replace with the goal id that matches your case).
- Rules Actions:

  - "***`Fetch entity by id`***", whereas the entity is a goal, and the id of it is (also) "`2`" (replace with the goal id that matches your case).
  - "***Show a message on the site***", which is just to demo / test some of the field values related to that goal (adapt the machine names of those fields to match your field names).

So by adding the Rules Condition "***`The goal completed by a user`***", and by also adding the Rules Action to "***`Fetch entity by id`***", in any subsequent Rules Action you should have access to all fields of the goal (with the goal id that matches your case).

Comment: Is there a way to do fetch the goal that was completed and triggered the rule? Seems like I would have to create a rule for each goal (and there are many of them).

Comment: @zoom-ping The question in your last comment here is actually a NEW question. Would you agree that my answer here DOES answer your original question, which is about "*find a way to fetch the completed goal entity*"? If so, how about marking this answer as "accepted", and then post a new question as a followup-question (with a link to this one)? After you do, I might also answer that new question (like "there is no out-of-the box answer with only the Goals module, but I can think of at least 1 alternative to create a single rule to cover all goals in it, provided you use an extra module also").

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try to phrase my question better.